# User selection for min bedrooms and max bedrooms - radio buttons?

Tags: selection, radio-buttons

I have a form that the user fills out. In this form the user chooses the bedrooms and bathrooms.

If I use radio buttons(as in the screen shot), I will need to code out logic to where the max radio choice can not be less than the  min radio choice.

I thought about using checkboxes instead and just have one column each for bedrooms and bathrooms. The issue I am worried about with check boxes is that the user won't realize they have to pick multiply selections and will think it's accumulative. For instance, if they want 1 or 2 bedrooms, I am worried that they would only check the box for 2 bedrooms and think it would include both 1 and 2 bedrooms, when in fact they only checked 2 bedrooms.

Are the radio buttons the best way to go to avoid this confusion?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using radio buttons for your task makes UI a bit confusing for users: they need to stop and think here. It creates excessive cognitive load and could break the flow.

Try more simple UI pattern for setting max and min values, which is used quite widely, watch an example from Ebay:

[image]

The other option is a range (slider) control, you can try is as well and conduct A/B testing to pick the best one.
[image]